# Issue with Accessing Microstack VM from Outside Network

Tags: openstack, microstack

I have an Ubuntu Instance (10.20.20.122) in Microstack. I can reach outside world from it but it is not reachable from outside network.For example, from the host (physical) LAN it is not reachable ( it is reachable only from host). There is a br-ex (10.20.20.1) bridge already available with the installation of Microstack.
My host is Ubuntu 1804 Desktop
Host IP is 193.166.x.y
I want to ping the instance from other hosts as well (such as 193.166.x.y1,y2,y3.. etc.).
Your help/suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks a million.

Comment: Provide more information. Is your instance connected to a provider network or a tenant network? Does it have a floating IP, and are you trying to connect to the floating IP? You say that it is reachable from the host - what do you do to reach it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for a solution. I've just published an approach to solve this problem in my blog. The link is:

https://connection.rnascimento.com/2021/03/08/openstack-single-node-microstack/

I've included some explanation why we can't change the default CIDR for br-ex and suggested a workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Actually, I managed it to comply with our LAN. I will check your blog for checking more details though.